Is Polars able to import SQLite BLOB fields?
I'm trying to import a SQLite table into a Polars df as follows:
import polars as pl

uri = "sqlite:///tmp/dbname.db"
query = ("SELECT * from alib")
df = pl.read_database_uri(query=query, uri=uri)

The first column in the SQLite table is called __path and its data type is BLOB.
When I try to import it into a Polars df it throws:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x/mypy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/polars/io/database/_utils.py", line 54, in _read_sql_connectorx
    tbl = cx.read_sql(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/x/mypy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/connectorx/__init__.py", line 386, in read_sql
    result = _read_sql(
             ^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Invalid column type Text at index: 0, name: __path
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/x/mypy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/polars/io/database/functions.py", line 396, in read_database_uri
    return _read_sql_connectorx(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/x/mypy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/polars/io/database/_utils.py", line 66, in _read_sql_connectorx
    raise type(err)(errmsg) from err
RuntimeError: Invalid column type Text at index: 0, name: __path
query = ("SELECT * from alib")
df = pl.read_database_uri(query=query, uri=uri)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x/mypy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/polars/io/database/_utils.py", line 54, in _read_sql_connectorx
    tbl = cx.read_sql(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/x/mypy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/connectorx/__init__.py", line 386, in read_sql
    result = _read_sql(
             ^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Invalid column type Text at index: 0, name: __path
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/x/mypy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/polars/io/database/functions.py", line 396, in read_database_uri
    return _read_sql_connectorx(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/x/mypy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/polars/io/database/_utils.py", line 66, in _read_sql_connectorx
    raise type(err)(errmsg) from err
RuntimeError: Invalid column type Text at index: 0, name: __path

Does Polars not handle SQLite BLOB fields at all or is there something I need to do to get working?
Schema as requested:
CREATE TABLE alib (
    __path                            BLOB UNIQUE,
    __filename                        BLOB,
    __dirpath                         BLOB,
    __filename_no_ext                 BLOB,
    __ext                             BLOB,
    __accessed                        TEXT,
    __app                             TEXT,
    __bitrate                         TEXT,
    __bitspersample                   TEXT,
    __bitrate_num                     TEXT,
    __frequency_num                   TEXT,
    __frequency                       TEXT,
    __channels                        TEXT,
    __created                         TEXT,
    __dirname                         TEXT,
    __file_access_date                TEXT,
    __file_access_datetime            TEXT,
    __file_access_datetime_raw        TEXT,
    __file_create_date                TEXT,
    __file_create_datetime            TEXT,
    __file_create_datetime_raw        TEXT,
    __file_mod_date                   TEXT,
    __file_mod_datetime               TEXT,
    __file_mod_datetime_raw           TEXT,
    __file_size                       TEXT,
    __file_size_bytes                 TEXT,
    __file_size_kb                    TEXT,
    __file_size_mb                    TEXT,
    __filetype                        TEXT,
    __image_mimetype                  TEXT,
    __image_type                      TEXT,
    __layer                           TEXT,
    __length                          TEXT,
    __length_seconds                  TEXT,
    __mode                            TEXT,
    __modified                        TEXT,
    __num_images                      TEXT,
    __parent_dir                      TEXT,
    __size                            TEXT,
    __tag                             TEXT,
    __tag_read                        TEXT,
    __version                         TEXT,
    __vendorstring                    TEXT,
    __md5sig                          TEXT,
    tagminder_uuid                    BLOB,
    sqlmodded                         TEXT,
    reflac                            TEXT,
    discnumber                        TEXT,
    track                             TEXT,
    title                             TEXT,
    subtitle                          TEXT,
    work                              TEXT,
    part                              TEXT,
    live                              TEXT,
    composer                          TEXT,
    arranger                          TEXT,
    lyricist                          TEXT,
    writer                            TEXT,
    artist                            TEXT,
    performer                         TEXT,
    personnel                         TEXT,
    conductor                         TEXT,
    engineer                          TEXT,
    producer                          TEXT,
    mixer                             TEXT,
    remixer                           TEXT,
    albumartist                       TEXT,
    discsubtitle                      TEXT,
    album                             TEXT,
    version                           TEXT,
    releasetype                       TEXT,
    year                              TEXT,
    originaldate                      TEXT,
    originalreleasedate               TEXT,
    originalyear                      TEXT,
    genre                             TEXT,
    style                             TEXT,
    mood                              TEXT,
    theme                             TEXT,
    rating                            TEXT,
    compilation                       TEXT,
    bootleg                           TEXT,
    label                             TEXT,
    musicbrainz_albumartistid         TEXT,
    musicbrainz_albumid               TEXT,
    musicbrainz_artistid              TEXT,
    musicbrainz_composerid            TEXT,
    musicbrainz_discid                TEXT,
    musicbrainz_producerid            TEXT,
    musicbrainz_releasegroupid        TEXT,
    musicbrainz_releasetrackid        TEXT,
    musicbrainz_trackid               TEXT,
    musicbrainz_workid                TEXT,
    lyrics                            TEXT,
    unsyncedlyrics                    TEXT,
    performancedate                   TEXT,
    acoustid_fingerprint              TEXT,
    acoustid_id                       TEXT,
    analysis                          TEXT,
    asin                              TEXT,
    barcode                           TEXT,
    catalog                           TEXT,
    catalognumber                     TEXT,
    country                           TEXT,
    discogs_artist_url                TEXT,
    discogs_release_url               TEXT,
    fingerprint                       TEXT,
    isrc                              TEXT,
    recordinglocation                 TEXT,
    recordingstartdate                TEXT,
    replaygain_album_gain             TEXT,
    replaygain_album_peak             TEXT,
    replaygain_track_gain             TEXT,
    replaygain_track_peak             TEXT,
    review                            TEXT,
    upc                               TEXT,
    musicip_data                      TEXT,
    type                              TEXT,
    musicip_puid                      TEXT,
    movement                          TEXT
);


Can you post the actual schema of your table? I changed the query to "SELECT randomblob(16)" and it worked and returned a column of type binary.

Added schema to original post.

I think you might have data with incorrect types somewhere in the column. select typeof(__path), count(*) from alib group by typeof(__path); <- this will print the actual types stored in the __path column along with their frequencies. Can you try running it from SQLite CLI or anywhere else?

(See also: https://sqlite.org/quirks.html#flexible_typing)

If you select all except for blob column what happens?

Dogbert: all records come back as text.
@RyoMatsuzaka, the table loads as expected.

Why you need blob column in SQL. You can hold data by saving path to blob and blob in blob storage like s3.

The table is defined and generated by a 3rd party and all data is written to a SQLite table.  Nothing I can do about that.  SQLite and Pandas have no problem processing it.

You have invalid (likely text) data in your BLOB column. SQLite (unfortunately) allows mixed types in columns. To prevent this I would strongly suggest to only use SQLite with STRICT tables.
Look at the following example, t1 only contains BLOB values but t2 contains a mix of BLOB and TEXT values, t3 rejects this because it is strict:
sqlite> .open tmp.db
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t1 (b BLOB);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t2 (b BLOB);
sqlit3> CREATE TABLE t3 (b BLOB) STRICT;
sqlite> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (x'0001');
sqlite> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (x'0001'), ('text');
sqlite> INSERT INTO t3 VALUES (x'0001'), ('text');
Runtime error: cannot store TEXT value in BLOB column t3.b (19)
sqlite> .exit

>>> import polars as pl
>>> pl.read_database_uri(query="SELECT * FROM t1", uri="sqlite://tmp.db")
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────┐
│ b           │
│ ---         │
│ binary      │
╞═════════════╡
│ b"\x00\x01" │
└─────────────┘
>>> pl.read_database_uri(query="SELECT * FROM t2", uri="sqlite://tmp.db")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/orlp/programming/rust/polars/py-polars/polars/io/database/_utils.py", line 54, in _read_sql_connectorx
    tbl = cx.read_sql(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/orlp/programming/rust/polars/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/connectorx/__init__.py", line 386, in read_sql
    result = _read_sql(
             ^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Invalid column type Text at index: 0, name: b

You can fix it by casting the column to blob, which then will get read as binary:
>>> pl.read_database_uri(query="SELECT cast(b as BLOB) FROM t2", uri="sqlite://tmp.db")
shape: (2, 1)
┌─────────────────┐
│ CAST(b AS BLOB) │
│ ---             │
│ binary          │
╞═════════════════╡
│ b"\x00\x01"     │
│ b"text"         │
└─────────────────┘

